# Could not find an ESM in the cluster. Groups: [localcloud]

Tags: cloudify

I tried to upload an application:

POST http://IP_VM_MNG:8100/2.7.1/upload/recipe.zip

and to deploy that:

POST http://IP_VM_MNG:8100/2.7.1/deployments/app_name

The response to deploy was:

```
{
"message": "Could not find an ESM in the cluster. Groups: [localcloud]",
"response": null,
"status": "Failed",
"verbose": "org.cloudifysource.rest.controllers.RestErrorException: esm_missing\n\tat org.cloudifysource.rest.validators.ValidateEsmExists.validateEsmExists(ValidateEsmExists.java:53)\n\tat org.cloudifysource.rest.validators.ValidateEsmExists.validate(ValidateEsmExists.java:39)\n\tat org.cloudifysource.rest.controllers.DeploymentsController.validateInstallApplication(DeploymentsController.java:860)\n\tat org.cloudifysource.rest.controllers.DeploymentsController.installApplication(DeploymentsController.java:756)\n\tat sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor331.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:91)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)\n\tat org.openspaces.pu.container.jee.stats.RequestStatisticsFilter.doFilter(RequestStatisticsFilter.java:77)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:453)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:560)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:937)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:998)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:856)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)\n",
"messageId": "esm_missing"
}
```

Can someone help me to understand the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ESM is the Elastic Service Manager - Cloudify's orchestrator. For some reason, when the REST API call arrived at the Cloudify manager, it could not find the ESM (there should always be one running).

You need to look at the cloudify web-ui and see if you can find the orchestrator component. You can also look at the logs of the agent on the relevant machine - if the ESM crashed and failed to restart, you should see some indication there.

In general, even if the ESM failed, it should restart automatically. Is it possible that your machine is maxed out on memory or CPU? That could cause network discovery issues.

Also, please bear in mind the Cloudify 2 has reached end of life - you may want to consider moving to Cloudify 3